# Remove the web apps from the G Suite Admin Console by using Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-admin-sdk, google-workspace

Suppose I have list of web apps in G Suite Admin console. I want to remove the web apps from the list. I know i can  remove my web app from admin console one by one.
But I want to remove (or revoke) the web apps using Google Apps Script. Can we do it?

Will this code do the trick?

```
var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/revoke?token=" + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken());
Logger.log(res.getResponseCode());
```

Comment: The question doesn't appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, and show a specific roadblock you're running into with [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For more information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: [Edit]  your question to include the code. See [ask] and [mre]. You shouldn't be asking: *Will it work?* Try and if you run into problems, post [mre] with a specific error

Comment: What do you mean by "webapps"? Could you add screenshots of what you are trying to automate?

Comment: i dont have screen shot but web apps is some  web application i.e to  publish the script as a web app.

Comment: @ManjuParihar are you refering to an Apps Script Project that you are Publishing as an Web-App? How are you seeing them on your admin console?

Comment: yes. Apps Script Project that we are Publishing as an Web-App.The third party web app is displayed as a list in  admin console. i want to remove any web app from the list using the Apps script.

Answer (score 1):

The code that is included in the question will not do "the trick".

You need to use the [G Suite Admin SDK Directory API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/). Fortunately, Google Apps Script has it as an Advanced Service -> [Admin SDK Directory Service](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/).

At this time it's not possible to uninstall / revoke domain-wide installed apps but it's possible to do this on a user by user basis.

By using this service, first you should get a list of the domain users, then get the tokens. From each token you should get the clientId, then using the user primary email address and the clientId you could delete the token so the web app will not be able to access the user data and do things on behalf the users anymore but bear in mind that they could authorize these apps again unless you disable this permission on the G Suite Admin Console.